# check if table-column contains at least one value != 0

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
id   |   name   |  priceEUR  | priceCHF  | priceUK  | priceRUB
--------------------------------------------------------------
1    |   00A    |      0     |     0     |     0    |     0
2    |   00B    |     10     |     0     |     0    |     0
3    |   00C    |      0     |     0     |    20    |     0
4    |   00D    |      0     |     0     |     0    |     0
5    |   00E    |      0     |    50     |     0    |     0
6    |   00F    |      0     |     0     |     0    |     0
7    |   00G    |      0     |     0     |     0    |     0
8    |   00H    |     12     |     0     |     0    |     0
9    |   00I    |      0     |    13     |    70    |     0
..   |   ...    |     ..     |    ..     |    ..    |    ..
n    |   99Z    |      0     |     1     |     0    |     0
```

I need to know for each column if the column, in the entire table, holds **at least one** `price != 0`, so the result should be something like this:

```
priceEUR  |  priceCHF  |  priceUK  |  priceRUB
----------------------------------------------
    10    |    50      |    20     |    0
```

It's not important that the returned value is the highest in the column, I need only to know if for that specific price there's one `value != 0`.

Please note that those columns have type `TEXT`. It's possible to achieve this result in just one query?

Comment: If you don't care about the value why not just `select sum(priceEUR),sum(priceCHF),sum(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT MAX(priceEUR),MAX(PriceCHF),MAX(priceUK),MAX(priceRUB)
from myTABLE
```